# Best practice to access outer aggregate class

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I'm currently working on an WPF application that has a main window that contains a panel whose content can be interchanged to show different User Controls. Basically, this just means that I have a menu with a constantly visible side-bar.

My question is about reducing the coupling between my classes. I have a notification section (in the form of a ListBox) in my main window where messages can pop up. The notifications can be "triggered" from actions happening in some User Controls (UCs). These User Controls are of course members of the Main Window class.

Since I need to affect the ListBox control in the Main Window class, I was wondering what the **best practice** would be. Obviously, the easiest solution would just be to pass a reference to the Main Window to each of the UCs through their constructor, but that doesn't seem very efficient on many levels. And I could of course only pass the ListBox element, but that wouldn't really work either since I have to perform operations on the data being added to the ListBox, and I would therefore have to programmatically repeat those instruction in each and every UC.

I could go with a singleton that would have a reference to the ListBox and implement the notification methods, but I already have more singletons that I'm comfortable with in my project (and I dont want EVERYONE to be able to access these methods, only certain UCs).

Another method would be to pass a Notification Manager instance (that would do the same job) through the concerned UCs' constructor. That manager would in turn have all the necessary methods to link the UCs to the main window.

There might be additional, more efficient solutions I haven't thought of. I want your opinion on the best practice in that kind of a case, especially considering the class coupling it generates. It can be related to this specific problem, but think of it in a more general way, where an inner aggregate class need to access some of the outer's resources. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Jesse's idea to raise an event: It's very WPF-ish and would allow loose coupling between the `UserControl` that needs to log stuff and the window that provides logging. Further more, the UserControls that do logging don't depend on logging services actually being available, and this would make the solution even more flexible.

### How this would work

The `UserControl` that needs logging simply raises a bubbling event that includes the relevant information (the text message to be logged). The UC will have no idea how or even if that message will be handled, it just raises it. It's a light-weight operation and the coupling is minimum.

The raised message bubbles it's way up the hierarchy chain, all the way to the top-level element (`Window`, `Page`). Anywhere along the way an element could provide a handler for this event type and through it be notified about the log request. Again, the coupling is very loose: The place where the implementation is made doesn't care who sent the message. Could be a UserControl or anything else.

### Problems

This works absolutely fine if an `UIElement` is available to be used as origin for the logging message event.

### Here's a step-by-step implementation:

### LogServices class

We can't re-use an existing event for this purpose, a new one needs to be created (to avoid confusion). This should do it:

```
// Subclass of RoutedEventArgs that allows us to easily and nicely pass the message
// to be logged
public class LogEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public LogEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, Object sender, string Msg)
        :base(routedEvent, sender)
    {
        this.Msg = Msg;
    }
}

// This is the Delegate that's used to grab the Log message
public delegate void RoutedLogEventHandler(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);

// This works as the abstraction layer that will allow UC's to raise LOG messages
// and allow your implementation to alter the way it handles those LOG messages.
// Since we're doing this with a routed event, we need an DependencyObject to
// reigster it.
public class LogServices :UIElement
{        
    public static RoutedEvent LogEvent;

    // Static constructor, registers the event
    static LogServices()
    {
        LogEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Log", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedLogEventHandler), typeof(UIElement));
    }

    // This helps raise the relevant shared event
    public static void RaiseLog(string Msg, UIElement sender)
    {
        sender.RaiseEvent(new LogEventArgs(LogEvent, sender, Msg)); 
    }

}
```

The code above declares sub-classes the `RoutedEventArgs` because we need to pass along our string Message. Then it creates the new delegate type that takes our `LogEventArgs` parameter and finally registers the event from the static constructor of `LogServices`.

### How to send an event

Sending an event is super-easy. This the Click handler for a button:

```
LogServices.RaiseLog("Message to be logged.", sender as Button)
```

### Receiving the event

Our event is registered as a "bubbling" event: It'll start from the control where we're raising it and give every parent a chance to handle it, all the way to the Window. The easiest thing to do is to handle the event in the `Window` that does logging. Unfortunately this type of shared can't be set straight from the `XAML`, it needs to be assigned from code. This is how I tried assigning it from the `XAML` and it didn't work:

```
<Grid local:LogService.Log="HandlerName" />
```

The next option is to assign it from code. Here's a snip from my test `Window1`:

```
    // Window Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set the event handler.
        base.AddHandler(LogServices.LogEvent, new RoutedLogEventHandler(HandleMsgLog));
    }

    // This is the actual handler.
    public void HandleMsgLog(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Put the received message into the ListBox
        LB.Items.Add((e as LogEventArgs).Msg);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response, using events is something I had not thought of. It is indeed a very low coupling solution.

Comment: I have another quick question: can (or rather should) the static LogServices class be used to contain and define other types of events (not necessarily related to the original) ? I'm asking since I really like the pattern you provided and would be interested to see its extent and re usability.

Comment: The `LogServices` works as a light-weight repository for the `LogEvent` structure (of type `RoutedEvent`), that's in essence all that it does. You need it because all the code that raises the event (*sends log messages*) or handles the events (*processes log messages*) need access to the structure. You can stuff as many events as you need in that class, but every one will need it's own `RoutedEvent` field. You might want to change the name of the class from `LogServices` to `Services` to keep it meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about observer pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) but this pattern more widely used than your situation.

In your situation I think good variants are:

1) Another method would be to pass a Notification Manager instance (that would do the same job) through the concerned UCs' constructor. That manager would in turn have all the necessary methods to link the UCs to the main window. (c)

2) All UC must implement  interface with event like 'NotificationRaised' and in your main window you need to subscribe on this event. About that said Jesse in comment to your question